# How to make a simple timer without new class in Android?

Tags: java, android, timer

I'm developing a Service for Android, that must run in background, executing a function each 100 seconds. That's the source code (example)

```
package com.example

import ....

public class Servizio extends Service {

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    }

    public void onCreate() {

    }

    public void onDestroy() {

    //here put the code that stop the timer cycle

    }

    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {

    //i want to begin here the timercycle that each 100 s call myCycle()

    }

    public void myCycle() {

    //code that i can't move on other class!!!

    }

}
```

How I can do that? Now the service execute myCycle() just one time, beacause I put a calling in onStart().

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) with a [TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html). To execute your method every 100 seconds, you can use the following in your `onStart` method. Be aware that this method creates a new thread.

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
     @Override
     public void run() {
         myCycle();
     }
}, 0, 100000);
```

Alternatively, use an [android.os.Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) as described in this article: [Updating the UI from a Timer](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/timed-ui-updates.html). It is better than a Timer because it runs in the main thread, avoiding the overhead of a second thread.

```
private Handler handler = new Handler();
Runnable task = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myCycle();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 100000);
    }
};
handler.removeCallbacks(task);
handler.post(task);
```

Comment: I didn't "poach" your answer. I had already written mine. Yours was wrong anyway.

Comment: Sorry but there is a problem i think due to the fact that use timertask...Logcat give me an error that stop the app: "Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()" relative to this line in my code "SurfaceView view = new SurfaceView(this);" Is there any other way?

Comment: @JPM yours answer are ok but they don't work...timertask is a  new class?

Comment: @Lork I have updated my answer to show how you would do it using a `Handler`. See if it works.

Comment: Technically none of our answers work as they are using new classes that would require changes to the myCycle...but without seeing myCycle() and whats in it I can't say for sure.

Comment: Glad you suggested Handler.postDelayed. <g>

Answer (score 2):

I usually do this, if I understood correctly you wanted the myCycle to execute every 100 secs.

```
Timer myTimer = new Timer();
myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        myCycle();
    }
}, 0,100000);
```

Answer (score 1):

When I had this issue, where I call out to a webservice on a periodic basis this was my solution:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    public static final int ONE_MINUTE = 60000;
    private Runnable periodicTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            mHandler.postDelayed(periodicTask, 100 * ONE_MINUTE);
            token = retrieveToken();
            callWebService(token);
        }
    };
```

I call the postDelayed early so that the delay from the webservice call doesn't cause the timing to shift.

The two functions are actually in the `MyService` class.

**UPDATE:**

You can pass a Runnable to postDelayed as shown here:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed(java.lang.Runnable, long)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#postDelayed%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long%29)

> public final boolean postDelayed (Runnable r, long delayMillis)
>
> Since: API Level 1 Causes the Runnable r to be added to the message
>   queue, to be run after the specified amount of time elapses. The
>   runnable will be run on the thread to which this handler is attached.

Also, my code won't compile due to missing functions, this is shown as an example of what the OP can do.

Comment: this won't compile. You need to pass `this`, not `periodicTask` to `postDelayed`.

Comment: @dogbane - I took what I had, as a demonstration, and it did compile. I took out some lines, but my periodicTask is almost untouched from what I am currently using.

Comment: @james-black, sorry my bad. Didn't see that they were instance variables.