# Using Timer in Android

Tags: android, timer

I have a class extends Activity in which I would like to run a (non-static) method every x seconds.
I've found some Timer tutorials, but in every single one, i have to create a new timer-class into my activity-class.
From this timer-class i'm not able to call my method in the activity class (because it's not static).
I hope you understand my problem and I would be very grateful for your help!

Comment: Do you want it to run every x seconds regardless of the activity lifecycle?

Comment: no, just during the activity lifecycle

Comment: What do you want this method to do that it cannot be static?

Comment: Actually I've found, what i was looking for:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7433510/1218336
thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2):

try Alarm Manager.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html